# Equivalence in Injective Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Can u help me prove the following statement

[Statement about injective Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhWN3.png)

Proving the fact that if it is injective the sequence splits seems easy and i did it. Now the other way around ive tried using that fact that if the sequence splits then there exists inverse homomorphisms and i tried working with them but i didnt have any success. So any help is appreciated , thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It is usually better to include the statement of your question in the body of the text, rather than linking to it: the easier it is to see your question, the more likely it is that someone will answer it.  (You can modify your question by clicking "edit").

Comment: Pehaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1877465/110831) contains the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon: If you type `[edit]` in a comment, then it links to the edit tools of the post at hand, whether that be a question or an answer. Look: [edit].

Comment: @Shaun Thanks! I did not know of this very useful feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the converse, if you have a diagram
\begin{alignat}{3}
0\longrightarrow& M\longrightarrow N\\
&\downarrow \\
&\:I
\end{alignat}
consider the  *amalgamated sum* $\;I\coprod\limits_M N$ and the canonical injection
$$0\longrightarrow I\longrightarrow I\coprod\limits_M N,$$
which has a *retraction* by the hypothesis on $I$. Compose it with the canonical injection $N\longrightarrow I\coprod\limits_M N$.

Comment: Im not familiar with the concept of an amalgamated sum and i didnt define it in my algebra course so i dont know :( , but thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Did you see fiber products? It's the dual notion.

Comment: No sorry, im afraid i didnt go that far :/

Comment: The amalgamated sum isnt't very complex: with the present notations, you consider the direct sum $I\oplus N$, and quotient out by the submodule consisting of $\bigl(f(m), -u(m)\bigr)$ for all $m\in M$, where $f:M\to I$ and $u:M\to N$.

Comment: Alright it doesnt seem very complicated , ill take a look into it , thx